# Did David become Saul's armor bearer before or after he killed Goliath?

Tags: word-study

In 1st Sam 16:17-23 Saul sent for David

However in 1st Sam 17:55-56 after he killed Goliath 
Saul asks Abner who he was

In 1st Sam 18:2 he did not let him return home

Answer (score 1):

Answer: David becomes Saul's armor bearer before he kills Goliath.

***Key Point:*** **The question in 17:55-56 is not "*who is he?*" but "*whose son is he*?"**

> And when Saul saw David go forth against the Philistine, he said unto Abner, the captain of the host, **Abner, whose son is this youth?** And Abner said, As thy soul liveth, O king, I cannot tell.  And the king said, **Enquire thou whose son the stripling is**.

Note that David never says (anywhere in chapter 17), "I'm David" or "I'm David, son of Jesse," he only names his father when prompted (after the killing of Goliath).

> And Saul said to him, **Whose son art thou, thou young man?** And David answered, **I am the son of thy servant Jesse the Bethlehemite.**

Nowhere does it say that Saul didn't recognize David.  Saul knew who he was. David had served Saul as a player and armorbearer (1 Samuel 16:17-23), but that doesn't mean Saul had any interest in his family.  Why would he? This changes in chapter 17 because of the promises Saul had made to whoever would kill Goliath:

> And the men of Israel said, Have ye seen this man that is come up? surely to defy Israel is he come up: and it shall be, that the man who killeth him, the king will enrich him with great riches, and **will give him his daughter, and make his father's house free in Israel**. (17:25)

The matter of David's family has now become very important, hence the question in 17:55-56.

***Regarding David's whereabouts between chapters 16 and 17:***
Verse 17:15 states that David returned (or had returned) from Saul to his father's land.

> But David went and **returned from Saul** to feed his father's sheep at Bethlehem.

After killing Goliath, verse 18:2 says that David no longer goes back and forth between his father's home and Saul's court.

> And Saul took him that day, and would let him **go no more home to his father's house**.

David was a servant of Saul (player, armorbearer) but was not a permanent fixture at Saul's court.  After killing Goliath his position elevated quickly and he did not return home again.

The chronology holds together fine as recorded:
1 Samuel 16:17 - Saul calls for a player
1 Samuel 16:21 - David comes to Saul and becomes his armorbearer
1 Samuel 16:22 - Saul requests that David stay for an extended period
1 Samuel 16:23 - David plays for Saul
1 Samuel 17:8 - Goliath challenges Israel
1 Samuel 17:15 - David returns home (or had returned home)
1 Samuel 17:20 - David arrives at the battle with food for his brothers
1 Samuel 17:26 - David makes public comments regarding Goliath
1 Samuel 17:31 - Saul sends for David after hearing his words through the grapevine
1 Samuel 17:32 - David agrees to fight Goliath
1 Samuel 17:55 - Saul asks Abner about David's lineage while David is facing Goliath
1 Samuel 17:58 - Saul asks David about his lineage directly
1 Samuel 18:2 - Saul takes David and David does not return home again

Note: There are no contradictions recorded here.  There is nothing to be glossed over or explained away.  It all follows as a straightforward story if you can accept the fact that Saul didn't memorize the family history of all his servants.

Answer (score 0):

David killed Goliath after. Chapter 17 tels us that David had gone home prior to his father sending him back to the battle with food for his brothers. And David indeed killed Goliath. 1 Chronicles 20:5 names Lahmi as the brother of Goliath who was slain by Elhanan. Thus giving the reason for the italicized correction in 2 Samuel 21.

Answer (score -1):

David had already had intimate acquaintance with Saul, when he became the king's armour bearer and then his personal musician.

> [1 Samuel 16:17-23](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1-Samuel-Chapter-16/): And Saul said unto his servants, Provide me now a man that can play well, and bring him to me. Then answered one of the servants, and said, Behold, I have seen a son of Jesse the Bethlehemite, that is cunning in playing, and a mighty valiant man, and a man of war, and prudent in matters, and a comely person, and the LORD is with him. Wherefore Saul sent messengers unto Jesse, and said, Send me David thy son, which is with the sheep. And Jesse took an ass laden with bread, and a bottle of wine, and a kid, and sent them by David his son unto Saul. And David came to Saul, and stood before him: and he loved him greatly; and he became his armourbearer. And Saul sent to Jesse, saying, Let David, I pray thee, stand before me; for he hath found favour in my sight. And it came to pass, when the evil spirit from God was upon Saul, that David took an harp, and played with his hand: so Saul was refreshed, and was well, and the evil spirit departed from him.

A little later, David told Saul that he would fight Goliath, so Saul offered him his own personal armour, but did not appear to recognise David (1 Samuel 17:31-35). His failure to recognise David is compounded because David is once again a shepherd boy, not a member of Saul's court, and has to come out of his father's fields to the battle.

When Saul saw David go to fight Goliath, he again asked who David was, in spite of David having explained this a short time earlier:

> [1 Samuel 17:55-56](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1-Samuel-Chapter-17/): And when Saul saw David go forth against the Philistine, he said unto Abner, the captain of the host, Abner, whose son is this youth? And Abner said, As thy soul liveth, O king, I cannot tell. And the king said, Enquire thou whose son the stripling is

Again, after David had slain Goliath, Saul had the young warrior brought to him, but once again did not recognise David:

> 1 Samuel 17:57-58: And as David returned from the slaughter of the Philistine, Abner took him, and brought him before Saul with the head of the Philistine in his hand. And Saul said to him, Whose son art thou, thou young man? And David answered, I am the son of thy servant Jesse the Bethlehemite.

---

The likely explanation for this is that the account blends together several different legends, without attempting to harmonise them. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David#Academic_views_on_the_biblical_account) cites Jacob L. Wright, Associate Professor of Hebrew Bible at Emory University, who has written that the most popular legends about David, including his killing of Goliath, are the creation of those who lived generations after him, in particular those living in the late Persian or Hellenistic period. The story of Goliath was probably added after the Book of Chronicles was written, because, although apparently a late rewrite of the Deuteronomic History, *Chronicles* does not contain this story of David killing Goliath.

2 Samuel 21:19 says that Elhanan killed Goliath (note that the KJV inserts 'brother of' to avoid a conflict with the story of David, but this is in italics to show that it is not original to the text). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David#David_and_Goliath) also cites Baruch Halpern, who suggested that storytellers most likely displaced the deed from the otherwise obscure Elhanan onto the more famous character, David.